# Is there any way to auto date format using Keyboarddatepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, material-ui, uidatepicker

We are using material ui Keyboarddatepicker, and we have set date format using props in react `format=DD/MMM/YYYY` so date will be set like "10/12/2020".

It is working perfectly when we select date from datepicker. But we are having problems when we enter the date manually or type it with another date format, like `dd/mm/yyyy`, or when we enter a numeric value. Then it should be set based on typed value, like when we type 10122000, then it should still be set in date format like "10/12/2020".

How can I convert all date input formats into our required date format?

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider libInstance={moment} utils={MomentUtils}>
  <KeyboardDatePicker autoOk={true} value={selectedDate} format="DD/MMM/YYYY" onChange={handleDateChange} />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```js
function transformDate(inputString) {
  const inputDateUS = new Date(inputString);
  const inputDateFr = new Date(inputDateUS.getFullYear(), inputDateUS.getDate() - 1, inputDateUS.getMonth() + 1)
  const formattedDate = inputDateFr.toLocaleString('default', { day: "numeric", month: "short", year: "numeric" });
  return formattedDate.split(" ").join("/");
}


// 10/01/2020 is transformed correctly
console.log(transformDate("10/01/2020"));

// 10-01-2020 is transformed correctly
console.log(transformDate("10-01-2020"));
```

As you can see, whatever the European format date that you enter, the funtion will output the format that you want, that is **DD/MMM/YYYY**.

Now all you have to do is get the input of the Date Picker, pass it to the function, then display the output (give the result back to the date picker).

In **your case**, replace `value={selectedDate}` with `value={transformDate(selectedDate)}`

Hope it helps

Comment: toLocaleFormat() method is deprecated. It is not working with modern browser.  If I enter any other date format or numeric as string from keyboard. Then it should be automatically convert in required date format

Comment: Improved the script

Comment: improved the script means?.  
   Can you please give me same example which I want

Comment: Click on "Run code snippet" and see the result

Comment: Can you please add some images and code in your question?

Comment: Please check my components code and let us know

Comment: I have updated my question, please check it

Comment: Edited the end of my answer

Comment: Will it be work when user enter date manually or typed from keyboard with different date format or numaric value like 01012000.  Because with date picker selection it is working fine

Comment: You need to test it!! I'm just here to assist you!

Comment: It is not working  in my case like I have used ```{transformDate(selectedDate)}```.     It is set default date in date field and default date is 01-jan-1970.  And not able to edit date.  In react js is it possible to auto date format when user typed different date format then it should be on date field  display required date format same as date picker selection